# Git and (gitweb) and SVN both over HTTPS at same time

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, git, svn, virtual-host

I'm trying to run both a Git server over http and I already have SVN running over http as well. I'm runnning centos 6

My git.conf (located in /etc/httpd/conf.d/) file looks like

```
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap_module.so
LoadModule ldap_module        modules/mod_ldap.so



    ServerName blahblah/git/repos 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/git/repos 

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/server.key
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/git-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/git-access.log combined

    # Enable cgi-bin scripts
    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
    AddHandler cgi-script cgi


     # Configure Git HTTP Backend
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    SetEnv GITWEB_CONFIG /etc/gitweb.conf

    # Note: Serve static files directly
    AliasMatch ^/(.*/objects/[0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38})$          /var/www/git/$1
    AliasMatch ^/(.*/objects/pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}.(pack|idx))$ /var/www/git/$1
    # Note: Serve repository objects with Git HTTP backend 
    ScriptAliasMatch \
          "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
                      info/refs | \
                      objects/info/[^/]+ | \
                      git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
          /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/$1
    # Note: Serve HTML with Gitweb
    ScriptAlias / gitweb/gitweb.cgi


    # Turning on mod rewrite
    RewriteEngine on

    # Make the front page an internal rewrite to the gitweb script
    RewriteRule ^/$  /gitweb/gitweb.cgi [L]

    # Make shortcut for a repostitory, so URL like 
    # loads proper repository in Gitweb
    RewriteRule ^/(\w+\.git)$  /?p=$1 [L,P]

    # Route Git-Http-Backend
    ScriptAlias / /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/

    # Require Acces for all resources
    
     AuthLDAPURL "ldap://blah:3268/dc=blah,dc=blah?sAMAccountName?sub" NONE
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
        AuthzGroupFileAuthoritative off
        AuthzUserAuthoritative off
        AuthLDAPBindDN blah@blah
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "blah"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "blah"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap

        # Important, otherwise "(9)Bad file descriptor: Could not open password file: (null)"
        AuthUserFile /dev/null

        Require valid-user
```

My subversion.conf file looks like this (located in /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf)

```
<Location /repos>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /var/www/svn/repos

    # search user (192.168.1.1 is the IP address of the Active Directory server)
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://blah:3268/dc=blah,dc=blah?sAMAccountName?sub" NONE
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthzGroupFileAuthoritative off
    AuthzUserAuthoritative off
    AuthLDAPBindDN blah@blah
    AuthLDAPBindPassword blah
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "blah"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap

    # Important, otherwise "(9)Bad file descriptor: Could not open password file: (null)"
    AuthUserFile /dev/null

    Require valid-user
</Location>
```